# Twisted Import Error when using Scrapy in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, scrapy, twisted

I'm having the following error when trying to use Scrapy in Python 3.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and installing `python3-twisted` didn't solve the issue.

```
  File "/home/fran/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 150, in crawl
    crawler = self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/home/fran/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 166, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings)
  File "/home/fran/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.extensions = ExtensionManager.from_crawler(self)
  File "/home/fran/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 56, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/home/fran/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 32, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/home/fran/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/fran/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/memusage.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scrapy.mail import MailSender
  File "/home/fran/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/mail.py", line 23, in <module>
    from twisted.mail.smtp import ESMTPSenderFactory
ImportError: No module named 'twisted.mail.smtp'
```

Comment: Maybe try to install twisted `sudo apt-get install python-twisted`

Comment: Also tried that with no success

Comment: @FranGoitia, What version of scrapy are you using? It seems to me that you're using Scrapy<=1.0, which is NOT python3 compatible. This line 23 [`from twisted.mail.smtp import ESMTPSenderFactory`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0/scrapy/mail.py) was [moved in Scrapy 1.1](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.1/scrapy/mail.py). Please upgrade to Scrapy 1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrapy's Python 3 support is still in a beta stage and (according to the [release notes](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#beta-python-3-support))

> Sending emails is not supported

so it's unlikely you can do anything to fix this.

Comment: I don't need to send emails. Is there something I can change in settings.py to prevent this feature from being loaded and this module imported ?

Comment: Have you enabled `scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage` extension? If so, remove it in your `EXTENSIONS` dict. Also, I believe it's a bug in scrapy to fail importing this extension as [using mail is disabled by default](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#memusage-notify-mail) in settings for this extension.

Comment: `scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage` works with Python 3 and Scrapy 1.1 if you don't need mail notifications. Import of non-Python3-supported SMTP in Twisted is only [imported when needed](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.1/scrapy/mail.py#L108) in Scrapy 1.1 vs Scrapy 1.0

Answer (score 3):

> Scrapy does not support sending mail with Python 3.

It's a limitation of Twisted, which has not ported it's `twisted.mail` module yet!
(**Unfortunately, Pull request is pending**)

**See:**

1. [Twisted #8770](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8770)
2. [[#8770] Port twisted.mail.smtp to Python 3 #509](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/pull/509)

Comment: There is a PR but it's not up for review and it's missing a lot of test coverage.  Someone needs to step up and finish the development.